# Implement piece-wise function in Matlab Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, piecewise

Hellp,

I'm a little new to the Simulink environment in Matlab. So, I was trying to implement a piece-wise function in it, but I could't figure out how to do so. The function that I want to implement is the following one:

[image]

In those equations the only thing that changes with time is **x**. So could someone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Giving more information about my approach I'd like to add that my "first solution" was try to implement it using the `Matlab Function` bloc as suggested by am304. Bu,t I run into problems when I tried to compile it. So I moved one and developed the following solution, that works, but I find it a little to be a little rough.
[image]

Switch 1: uses `Vref` as threshold, 
Switch 2: uses `-Vref` as threshold, 
Switch 3: uses `-Vref` as threshold, 
Switch 4: uses `Vref` as threshold.

Comment: Show us what you tried...

Comment: @am304 added my solution. Thanks for or help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways in which this can be done: native Simulink blocks, Stateflow charts, MATLAB Function, etc...

Here's how I would do it with a [MATLAB Function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block:

```
function vcons = piecewise_fcn(x)

% Define Vref, kx, and x_stop

if kx*(x_stop - x) >= Vref
   vcons = Vref;
elseif kx*(x_stop - x) <= -Vref
   vcons = -Vref;
else
   vcons = kx*(x_stop - x);
end
```